# Initialise tree with adjacency list as input

Tags: java, tree

I'm trying to make a simple tree node class in java(instead of using TreeNode interface provided in javax.swing) which I can use for simple problems like finding height and checking if it is balanced.

```
class node{
    int data;
    node left;//left child node
    node right;//right child node
    int height;
    node(int data){
        this.data=data;
        left=null;
        right=null;
        height=0;
    } 
}
```

But how do I initialize it if input is taken as an adjacency list as follows:

```
1
2,3
1,4,5
1
2
2,6,7
5
5
```

where first line is the root node and following lines show the nodes adjacent to the node represented by the corresponding line number.it will look like this:
[image]

Also, please suggest any changes that I may incorporate in the node class so that it can be used for basic problems like finding height, checking if tree is balanced, breadth first search etc.

Comment: I don't understand your tree example. Could you describe it like this `(node, child1, chidl2, ..., childk)`?

Comment: First of all, you have to ask yourself if this is a tree or a more generic graph. Are you sure that all adjacency lists will be representing a tree? Also, in the adjacency list of a node, e.g. 5 - 2, 6, 7 - how do you know which is the parent and which are children?

Comment: yes, I'm sure all the inputs will be representing a binary tree. I will know which is the parent and which is the child if I start from the root node, which is given in the first line of the input

Comment: As others have said, could you give a more explicit example for the tree using the adjacency list? How would an adjacency list look like for a tree where `a` is the root and `b` and `c` are the only two children?

Comment: I have added the tree diagram for the given input case